# When exactly is Next.js “build-time” happening?

Tags: reactjs, next.js

I'm reading Next.js fetching data part of the documentation and one question came to my mind.

Next.js can fetch data with `getStaticProps`, `getStaticPaths`, `getInitialProps` and `getServerSideProps`, right?

But some happens on Build-time as I quote:

> getStaticProps (Static Generation): Fetch data at build-time

When is this Build-time happening?

Is it when we run `npm run build`? (To build the production build)

Or when the user accesses our Next.js app? (On each request)

Answer (score 102, accepted):

Build-time occurs when the app is compiled for production: `next build`

Run-time occurs when the app is running in production: `next start`

#### getInitialProps

This runs on both the client and the server during run-time for every page request. Most common use case is retrieving some sort of shared data (like a session that lets the client and server know if a user is navigating to a specific page) before the requested page loads. This always runs before getServerSideProps. While its usage is technically discouraged, sometimes it absolutely necessary to do some logic on both the client and server.

#### getServerSideProps

This only runs on the server during run-time for every page request. Most common use case would be to retrieve up-to-date, page-specific data (like a product's pricing and displaying how much of it is in stock) from a database before a page loads. This is important when you want a page to be search engine optimized (SEO), where the search engine indexes the most up-to-date site data (we wouldn't want our product to show "In stock - 100 units," when it's actually a discontinued product!).

#### getStaticProps

This only runs during build-time (sort of). It's great for sites whose data and pages don't update that often. The advantage of this approach is the page is statically generated, so if a user requests the page, they'll download an optimized page where the dynamic data is already baked into it. Most common use case would be a blog or some sort of large shopping catalog of products that may not change that often.

#### getStaticPaths

This only runs during build-time (sort of). It's great for pre-rendering similar paths (like a `/blog/:id`) that require dynamic data to be used at build-time. When used in conjunction with getStaticProps, it generates the dynamic pages from a database/flat file/some sort of data structure, which Next can then statically serve. An example use case would be a blog that has many blog posts which share the same page layout and similar page URL structure, but require the content to be dynamically baked into the page when the app is being built.

Why are getStaticProps and getStaticProps *sort of* ran during build-time? Well, Next introduced `revalidate` with `fallback` options that allows these two Nextjs functions to be ran during run-time after a timeout in seconds. This is useful if you want your page to be statically regenerated, but it should only be regenerated every n amount of seconds. The upside is that the page doesn't need to request dynamic data when navigated to, but the downside is that the page may initially show stale data. A page won't be regenerated until a user visits it (to trigger the revalidation), and then the same user (or another user) visits the same page to see the most up-to-date version of it. This has the unavoidable consequence of User A seeing stale data while user B sees accurate data. For some apps, this is no big deal, for others it's unacceptable(†).

† If you're using a version of Next v12.2.0+, you can use [On-demand Revalidation](https://nextjs.org/docs/basic-features/data-fetching/incremental-static-regeneration#on-demand-revalidation) to mitigate a stale static page from being shown to users if/when its data has been updated.

#### Client-Side Rendering

And lastly, there's client-side rendering which are assets requested at run-time on the client (the browser) which aren't vital for SEO; or, there's some JavaScript code that can't be run on the server. A common use case would be a user-specific dashboard page that is only relevant to that user and therefore doesn't need to be SEO. But, more commonly, there may be some sort of JavaScript that manipulates the DOM and therefore can't be run on the server because servers don't have a [DOM](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document_Object_Model/Introduction).

#### Notes

Please be aware that when using getInitialProps and getServerSideProps that they are render blocking. Meaning, the page will not load until their code resolves/returns props. This has the unavoidable consequence of showing a blank page before the page loads. In summary, this could result in a slower [TTI](https://web.dev/interactive/).

Comment: Thanks for this complete guide! 
One more question. So, for example, if I have a blog and retrieve all posts Ids with gSPaths (e.g 1, 2, 3) and I create a new post with I’d 4, I have to create a new production build to update the blog with that new post ?

Comment: If you use `revalidate` with `fallback` then no; otherwise, yes, then you'd have to rebuild.

Comment: Wow, NextJS is so powerful. Thanks for helping me understand more about this framework!

Comment: So if i use gsstaix o path, i need to run build from my computer manually? To see the new data? Its weird...

Comment: Yes and no. If you use gSPaths and gsProps with `revalidate` then no, you don't need to manually rebuild. Otherwise, yes. The primary purpose of gSPaths is resolve unknown paths from an API during **buildtime**. Without gSProps, there's no way to retrieve new data from an API during **runtime**. When used together, they progressively build **static pages** during runtime. In the future, they be able to implement a feature where a user doesn't need to fetch the page in order to revalidate; instead, pages will be rebuilt when data changes from the API.

Comment: what about if I want to fetch data just one time at build? like config JSON file via API and store this file as static inside the file system.

Comment: @Nurdindev If this data is used to statically build a page, then gSProps is all you need (no need to save it to disk if it's already in a database; otherwise it'll be saved to a disk twice). It'll be fetched ONCE when you run `npm run build` (or `yarn build`). If the data changes at all, then you'll need to manually rebuild.

Comment: Thank you so much. This helps me a lot to understand better how next js work. I can say it is better then the doc say.

Comment: More on revalidation, well explained: https://vercel.com/docs/next.js/incremental-static-regeneration

Comment: What a great informative and easy-to-understand answer. Thank you sir.

Comment: @MattCarlotta so when i am in dev mode and I have dev database , if I did npm run build will that be in the build code which when i deploy will be there? what about when I am in productiion?

Comment: @BishalRaEe - When building for production, you'll want to use production [environment variables](https://nextjs.org/docs/basic-features/environment-variables). If anything related to the database is hardcoded, then you'll be forced to manually change those hardcoded options every time you run `build` for either a local or remote production build. Now you may be thinking, how do I make production builds more flexible through Envs.,, you can't as of now. See [this RFC](https://github.com/vercel/next.js/discussions/25764). I've developed my own env loading package to get around this limitation.

Comment: @MattCarlotta what I am confused about is what data from database would you use in first build time when api/database has no data (generally the case at first deploy) as data are added when they are deployed from frontend

Comment: I'm still trying to understand the differences and when they're most applicable. Let's say I have a `todoList` component who's data changes often and is on the server, I would want to use `getServerSideProps` to get the latest data, right? I'm not really concerned about SEO, I just want to make sure that my dynamic `todoList` component always reflects the latest state of my todos in the database.

Comment: @HaulinOats If you're not concerned with SEO, then you can just use client-side requests/rendering. The gSSP method is useful when, during the **initial** page load, a bot/crawler won't be indexing a spinner/loading indicator, instead it can index the layout/data on the page without waiting (the dynamic data is already available in the HTML). If you don't plan on doing anything on the server-side nor statically generating pages based upon any data, then I'd recommend not using NextJS at all and just stick with a client-side only solution (like the [CRA](https://create-react-app.dev/)).

Comment: @MattCarlotta dude this is the entire nextjs documentation in short . Thanks a lot