# On a deployed Next.js site, when will getStaticProps and getServerSideProps functions run?

Tags: next.js

So I have a Next.js site deployed, and in Todos page ( https://learn-next-js-alpha.vercel.app/todos ) I am calling api data using getServerSideProps and it works fine. But even if I use getStaticProps it works. So what is the difference? Is it like getStaticProps and getServerSideProps run when a person visits this site and loads this data?
Also When a person hits the refresh page button, which method is called, getStaticsProps or getServerSideProps?

Comment: This can explain you better - https://nextjs.org/docs/basic-features/data-fetching

Comment: Does this answer your question? [When exaclty is Nextjs “build-time” happening?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64520234/when-exaclty-is-nextjs-build-time-happening)