# Is it the best way to call the api for seo with Next?

Tags: api, next.js

I am using swr to get the data from an api. I have doubts if it is actually done server-side. I would like to have good seo and load the  before loading the page. I have seen getServerSideProps () but I have doubts as I am new to react next

```
import React from "react";
import useSWR from "swr";

const fetcher = (url) => fetch(url).then((res) => res.json());

export default function App() {
    const { data, error } = useSWR(
        "my_url_api",
        fetcher
    );
    console.log(data);

    if (error) return "An error has occurred.";
    if (!data) return "Loading...";
    return (
        <div>
            <div>
                <h1>Esta es la web</h1>
            </div>
            {
                data.videos.map(({ item, title, embed, rate, default_thumb: { src } }) =>

                    <>
                        <h3>{title}</h3>
                        <img src={src} alt="Picture of the author" />
                        <iframe width="1225" height="625" src={embed}></iframe>
                        <p>{rate}</p>

                    </>
                )
            }
        </div>
    );
}
```

Comment: Does this help answer your question: [When exaclty is Nextjs “build-time” happening?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64520234/when-exaclty-is-nextjs-build-time-happening)?

Answer (score 0):

It varies based on your use case and the type of data you are fetching.
swr is for client side rendering.

check out this [doc](https://nextjs.org/learn/basics/data-fetching/request-time) to identify your usecase