# At what stage getStaticProps() fetch the data from my API?

Tags: next.js

I'm trying to understand when exactly does getStaticProps fetch the data.

is it on the build process or every time the website is been render to someone (every time someone visits my app)

if it's the first one, doesn't it make my app "static" meaning it won't update the data when the data on my DB is changed?

Thanks!!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [When exactly is Next.js “build-time” happening?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64520234/when-exactly-is-next-js-build-time-happening)

Answer (score 1):

I am going to sleep So I just copied below answer from [NextJS Docs](https://nextjs.org/docs/basic-features/data-fetching/incremental-static-regeneration)

Next.js allows you to create or update static pages after you’ve built your site. Incremental Static Regeneration (ISR) enables you to use static-generation on a per-page basis, without needing to rebuild the entire site. With ISR, you can retain the benefits of static while scaling to millions of pages.

To use ISR add the revalidate prop to `getStaticProps`:

```
function Blog({ posts }) {
  return (
    <ul>
      {posts.map((post) => (
        <li>{post.title}</li>
      ))}
    </ul>
  )
}
export async function getStaticProps() {
  const res = await fetch('https://.../posts')
  const posts = await res.json()

  return {
    props: {
      posts,
    },
    // Next.js will attempt to re-generate the page:
    // - When a request comes in
    // - At most once every 10 seconds
    revalidate: 10, // In seconds
  }
}
export async function getStaticPaths() {
  const res = await fetch('https://.../posts')
  const posts = await res.json()

  // Get the paths we want to pre-render based on posts
  const paths = posts.map((post) => ({
    params: { id: post.id },
  }))

  // We'll pre-render only these paths at build time.
  // { fallback: blocking } will server-render pages
  // on-demand if the path doesn't exist.
  return { paths, fallback: 'blocking' }
}
```

Comment: Thanks! I will have a look. But the ISR sounds cool =)