# What is the difference between getStaticProps() and getServerSideProps() in nextjs

Tags: next.js

What is the difference between **getStaticProps()** and **getServerSideProps()** in nextjs ?

Comment: See [When exactly is Next.js “build-time” happening?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64520234/when-exactly-is-next-js-build-time-happening).

Answer (score 3):

### GetStaticProps

- Use inside a page to fetch data at build time.
- This data will be part of your build. If data changed since the build, you wouldn't see it until you build again.
- Good if you only need to update that data once in a while, manually on each deployment.
- When you use getStaticProps you get the fastest performance
- Can potentially deliver stale data.
- Data is rendered before it gets to the client, server-side.

### GetServerSideProps

- Use it to fetch data for every instance that a user issues a request to the page
- Fetches on every client request, before sending the page to the client.
- Data is refreshed every time the user loads the page

Use cases:
For example, if you are fetching all the countries available in the world, makes sense to use getStaticProps. But if you need to retrieve user data, you should use getServerSideProps.

Answer (score 0):

**GetStaticSideProps**

It is a special function that tells Next JS to populate props and render the page that it is exported from into a static HTML page at build time.

- Fetch request is made only at build time.
- Data Integrity is low to none
- SEO friendly
- Instant performance
- Slow build time

**GetServerSideProps**

A special Next JS function that tells the Next component to populate the props and render into a static HTML page at run time.

- Fetch request is made at every page request.
- Data Integrity is High
- SEO friendly
- Loads before the render
- Fast build time

Answer (score 0):

the biggest difference is this

for using getStaticProps and getStaticPaths, you must create all pages of your site, after that, you can deploy site on server. it means that after you deployed, you can't add or edit a page of your site. for add or update, you should edit project, then deploy this again.
but with getserversideprops, you can edit or add or do any thing on your site.
for example, you can't design a weblog site with getStaticProps. because of you want to add a post any week. but with getserversideprops, you can do it.

after this difference, this is important. speed of getStaticProps is more than getserversideprops.